# Submit form with urllib Python 3.4

Tags: python, urllib, python-3.4

I want to login to a site with urllib in Python 3.4

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
url = 'http://mysite.org'
values = {"username" : "MyUsername123", 
          "password" : "MyPass123"}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
binary_data = data.encode('utf8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, binary_data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode("utf8", 'ignore')
print(response)
```

When i run this, the output is the login page, not the page after you log in.
In Python 2.7 i did it with mechanize, and now i can't because it's not compatible with 3.4.

Comment: Can't you use the requests package? It'd make your life easier: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Is there any from field errors in your `response`?

Comment: No errors, my response is the login page.